# How to remove items from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a GridView that displays the items from the database. I want to delete items from the database when i click the Delete linkbutton:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCategories" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" ItemType="webLicenta.Category"
    SelectMethod="GetCategories" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="Nr. Categorie" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Denumire categorie" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opțiuni">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteCategory" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried this, but no result:

```
protected void gvCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var _db = new webLicenta.MagazinDBEntities())
        {
            int categoryId = Convert.ToInt16(gvCategories.SelectedValue);
            var myItem = (from c in _db.Categories where c.CategoryID == categoryId select c).FirstOrDefault();
            if (myItem != null)
            {
                _db.Categories.Remove(myItem);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                string pageUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Count() - Request.Url.Query.Count());
                Response.Redirect(pageUrl + "?CategoryAction=remove");
            }
```

Comment: Is the item deleted from the database? Is your table being re-rendered to reflect the database change? Have you set breakpoints inside of gvCategories_selectedIndexChanged to see if myItem is null?

Comment: No, there is no change to the database whatsoever. And i can't say if myItem is null, because i get an error when i insert breakpoints. I think the problem might be with the Event or the initialization of categoryId.

Comment: If you can't set breakpoints because of an error, then it's likely your code is not executing correctly, what is the error you receive when trying to set breakpoints?

Comment: I get error 500 when i try accesing the page with the gridview

Comment: Actually, i just noticed. I get error 500 no matter if i insert breakpoints or not.

Comment: maybe this will help you to solve your 500 error (https://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/working-past-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: This is the error: "A field or property with the name 'id' was not found on the selected data source."

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1L4BCkg A screen shot of the error, if it helps

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your datagrid and the columns in your database table, such as you are missing an id column in your database ?? Maybe this will help you (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q383587/aspxgridview-a-field-or-property-with-name-x-was-not-found-in-the-selected-datasource)